# How to initiate reopen voting after editing a question to clarify its meaning? [I don't have enough rep to vote to reopen.]

Tags: support

[What to call women whose husbands are biological brothers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394252/what-to-call-women-whose-husbands-are-biological-brothers)

This recent question by a new member was put on hold as unclear, and I edited the question to clarify the meaning. The edit took effect immediately because I have enough rep for that purpose, but I do not have nearly enough rep to vote for reopening. The related flag I raised asking a moderator to reopen was (rightly) declined because it is apparently not the moderator's function to reopen questions. So how do I  proceed? The defect which was the reason for putting the question on hold has been rectified, but it looks like nobody has yet voted to reopen, and the Q remains "on hold."

Note: my answer has already been accepted by OP but I should like to understand the procedure to reopen questions in this type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing any post will automatically push it onto the reopen review queue. But [conditions apply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/5832912).

Or, if you already have reopen privilege, just your vote to reopen will push it onto the queue.

Users with reopen privilege can vote to keep it closed or to reopen it within the review process.

Or asking on meta, just like you now did, will bring in attention from other users, who can then visit the page directly to vote to reopen it, if they want to.

Comment: Thank you -- asking on meta is a sort of manual 'last resort' but  it is good to know that *editing any post will automatically push it onto the reopen review queue* -- so my work is done and in any case, OP has got an answer to their question!

Comment: @EnglishStudent updated answer.

Comment: The update seems to indicate that editing an on-hold Q automatically pushes it into a reopen queue *only in certain situations*. If for some reason it does not automatically get enqueued, dont you think there should be some other way (other than asking a meta Q like this one) for a low-rep user to call the edit to the attention of reopen-empowered members?

Comment: @EnglishStudent why would you need 'another way'. Meta is there for these purposes. Use it.

Comment: @EnglishStudent check out user Sven Yargs's meta profile. He has requested reopening of a few good questions. Learn from his methods.

Comment: The meta question is always an option and the request for reopening 'a few good questions' by Sven Yargs is notable, but I thought there must be some merit to the original question, or something unique about it to justify making a meta question on its behalf. If this method can be used to draw attention to *any question after editing* it to correct the reason for putting it on hold, then I shall use the meta option for this purpose until I cross 3000 rep and get that reopen vote!

Comment: @EnglishStudent obviously there should be some merit to the question to make it reopen worthy. If it deserves a second chance, using meta to get others' input is a nice way to go about it. Simply reopening just about anything is not a good idea. (I on rare occasions may have cast a final vote to reopen some posts for no reason in particular, but that's another story)

Comment: This is a specific case of a question that was put on hold as 'not clear.' It is not an especially meritorious question but my edit to clarify has removed the reason for keeping it 'on hold.' This is the type of situation I was referring to: an unremarkable Q has been edited to 'fix' the reason for closing -- but your answer makes it clear that a low-rep member can use meta in all such cases to notify vote-empowered members that the Q is now fit to reopen.

Comment: @EnglishStudent also bear in mind that not all users will agree with your opinion about a question. So, some may vote to keep it closed, or maybe once it is reopened, some users will vote to close it anyway.

Comment: Very true. I am also aware (and have seen certain examples here) that a Q that was reopened after being closed for one reason, can then be closed for an entirely different reason! This particular question I was referring to is nothing special but it got closed as unclear only because OP could not word it properly. I have simply edited it for clarity and want voting members to know it. My edit was further improved by 2 senior members so the Q ought to be *very clear* by now! If somebody likes they can vote to reopen. Your kind explanation of the process & its internal logic is much appreciated!